# Connection between the Haag and the Currie-Jordan-Sudarshan (CJS) no-go theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, hamiltonian-formalism, interactions

The Currie-Jordan-Sudarshan (CJS) no-go theorem states, that in the setting of Hamiltonian mechanics, if the particle coordinates $q_i^{\alpha}$ (on the trajectory) transform correctly under the Poincare transformation, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\left[q_{i}^{\alpha}, P_{k}\right]=\delta_{i k}, \quad\left[q_{i}^{\alpha}, J_{k}\right]=-\varepsilon_{i k l} q_{l}^{\alpha}, \quad\left[q_{i}^{\alpha}, K_{k}\right]=q_{i}^{\alpha}\left[q_{k}^{\alpha}, H\right]
\end{equation}
(the world line condition) and the equation of motions are not degenerate
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{det} \frac{\partial^{2} H}{\partial p_{i}^{\alpha} \partial p_{k}^{\beta}} \neq 0
\end{equation}
then, there cannot be interaction, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\left[\left[q_{i}^{\alpha}, H\right], H\right]=0
\end{equation}
I have two questions:

1. What are the consequences of this theorem for Quantum mechanics/ Quantum field theory?
2. Is the theorem connected to Haag's theorem?

Comment: This is a theorem about classical Hamiltonian mechanics. Why would you think this has any effect on the quantum theory, and why would it be connected to Haag's theorem, which is a statement about relativistic interacting quantum *field* theories, not theories of interacting particles?

Comment: Because we could look at unitary representations of the poincare group. I.e. that there is no good position operator in relativistic quantum mechanics could be connected to the fact, that one solution to the no-go theorem is to stop using the canonical coordinates as particle positions.